# How to limit selectable checkboxes to 3 in recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have a recycler view which has checkboxes as items. I want to make sure there cannot be selected more than 3 checkboxes. If 3 checkboxes are selected other checkboxes should not be selectable, only selected checkboxes should be able to be deselected. I am not sure if I need to implement that behaviour in adapter or fragment which holds adapter. This is how my adapter looks like:

```
class HomeAdapter(
    private val listener: OnCheckBoxClickListener
) : ListAdapter<String, HomeAdapter.SurveyViewHolder>(HOME_COMPARATOR) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SurveyViewHolder {
        val bind = ItemHomeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return SurveyViewHolder(bind)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SurveyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let { holder.bind(it) }
    }

    inner class SurveyViewHolder(
        val binding: ItemHomeBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(answer: String) = with(binding) {
            checkBox.text = answer
        }

        init {
            binding.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                listener.onCheckBoxClickListener(
                    index = bindingAdapterPosition,
                    isChecked = isChecked,
                    answer = currentList[bindingAdapterPosition]
                )
            }
        }

    }

    interface OnCheckBoxClickListener {
        fun onCheckBoxClickListener(index: Int, isChecked: Boolean, answer: String)
    }

    companion object {
        private val HOME_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<String>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: String, newItem: String): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

}
```

So far, I have tried something like this in fragment:

```
   private fun countCheckedCheckBoxes() = with(binding) {
        var num = 0
        for (i in 0..recyclerView.childCount) {
            (recyclerView.getChildAt(i) as? CheckBox).also {
                if (it?.isChecked == true) {
                    num += 1
                }
            }
        }
        if (num == 3) {
            // TODO do something here
        }
    }
```

Comment: AS soon as three checkboxes are selected you set Enable to false of the other checkboxes. (Well you should have two boolean arrays for that. One who indicates the checked state. The other the enabled state) . You did not describe what should happen if one of the three selected boxes is deselected. Should all others become enabled again?

Comment: Yes, if one of three checkboxes is deselected all other checkboxes should be be selectable again. Can you describe in more details about those two bolean arrays. Should I put them in fragment or adapter?

Comment: In adapter. Like the other lists you will have for your adapter. You will need them too to keep the checked state when scrolling. How did you keep that state? Or add two booleans to your model class.

Comment: If you count checked boxes then do not count checked children but count how many booleaans in adapter are true.

Comment: Can you make a example, I don't understand what are you talking about

Comment: You did not even tell if a checked checkbox keeps it state at scroll and scroll back in view.

Comment: It should keep its state the whole time

Comment: Yes it should. But does it do so was the question.